# How do I remove all the groups from disabled Active Directory Users via Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, ou

I'm trying to gather all the disabled users in our Active Directory and trying to remove the disabled users from all their groups. Mostly for cleanup purposes. I'm a bit stuck on my script. I'm not sure what to put after `Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`:

```
$disabled_users = Get-AdUser -SearchBase "Ou=Users, Ou=test, DC=testdomain, DC=io" -Filter
  "enabled -eq 'false'"
 foreach($person in $disabled_users) {
     Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $person | Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership #stuckhere
 }
```

Comment: Does it not work as is? I did a quick `help remove-adprincipal...` and it shows that it accepts the same object type `get-adprinfipal...` returns.

Comment: No it kept asking for Memberof: whenever I tried running it.

Answer (score 0):

`Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` returns only groups, leading `Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` to auto-fill `-Identity` with the group name. You'll have to re-use the user object in `-Identity`.

Because of the first issue, `Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` doesn't accept multiple groups from the pipeline. It should normally, but the `[ADGroup]` objects returned by `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` seem to trip it up. To fix, use a `ForEach` loop, or use a two-step process:

```
# two steps:
$groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $person
Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $person -MemberOf $groups -WhatIf 

# OR foreach loop:
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $person | 
    Foreach { 
        Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $person -MemberOf $_
    }
```

Note that you can't remove an AD user's primary group (usually 'Domain Users'), so you may want to add a filter:

```
$groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $person |
    Where Name -notlike 'Domain Users'
Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $person -MemberOf $groups
```

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - Rather than editing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67200713/3744182) to include `Remove-ADGroupMember`, consider adding your own answer, as the edit may get rejected for conflicting with the author's intent.

Answer (score 0):

Adding another option using `Remove-ADGroupMember` instead:

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $person | Remove-ADGroupMember -Members $person
```

`Remove-ADGroupMember` will take the `distinguishedNames` of the user's membership as pipeline value so you only need to specify the **Member** of the group you want to remove.